Middleware Not Invoked After Authentication in API Gateway with Multi-Tenant Setup
I'm working on an API Gateway using Ocelot for request routing and IdentityServer4 for authentication. The setup involves a multi-tenant system, where the tenant information is resolved using the IMultiTenantContextAccessor from the query string.
The issue I'm facing is that none of the middlewares in my downstream services are being hit after the request is authenticated via the API Gateway. The tenant information remains null because the middleware responsible for resolving the tenant is never invoked. However, if I hit the downstream API directly (bypassing the gateway and authentication), everything works fine — the middlewares are executed, and the tenant is resolved correctly.
Here’s a breakdown of the setup:

API Gateway: Uses Ocelot and is configured with IdentityServer4 for authentication.
Downstream API: Implements multi-tenancy with middleware to resolve the tenant from the query string.
Problem: When a request is routed through the API Gateway and authenticated, the middlewares in the downstream service (like tenant resolution) are not invoked, causing the tenant to remain null. Without authentication, the downstream API works as expected, and the tenant is resolved properly

Configuration in ocelot.json:
{
  "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/{everything}",
  "DownstreamScheme": "http",
  "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
    {
      "Host": "localhost",
      "Port": 41582
    }
  ],
  "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/example-api/{everything}",
  "RateLimitOptions": {
    "ClientWhitelist": [],
    "EnableRateLimiting": true,
    "Period": "1s",
    "PeriodTimespan": 1,
    "Limit": 100
  },
  "AuthenticationOptions": {
    "AuthenticationProviderKey": "TestKey",
    "AllowedScopes": []
  },
  "Key": "example.api"
}


Middleware Pipeline in the Downstream API:
 app.UseMultiTenant();
 app.UseSerilogRequestLogging();
 app.UseCustomErrorHandlingMiddleware();
 app.UseSwagger();
 app.UseSwaggerUI();
 app.UseHttpsRedirection();
 app.UseAuthentication();
 app.UseAuthorization();
 app.MapControllers();
 app.Run();

What Works:
If I hit the downstream API **directly without going through the API Gateway **(i.e., without authentication), the middleware pipeline works fine, and the tenant is resolved correctly.
What Fails:
When the request is authenticated via the API Gateway, the downstream service middlewares (like UseMultiTenant()) never get executed, leaving the tenant null.
What I've Tried:

Checked the middleware order to ensure UseMultiTenant() is before UseAuthentication().
Enabled detailed logging in Ocelot but didn’t find any issues related to request forwarding.
Verified that the downstream API is properly configured to validate the token using AddJwtBearer.

Questions:

Why is the downstream service's middleware (like UseMultiTenant()) not being hit after authentication via the API Gateway?
How can I ensure that the tenant resolution middleware is invoked when the request passes through the API Gateway with authentication?

Any suggestions on what might be causing the middleware to be skipped or how to debug this would be greatly appreciated!
